# How to programmatically initialize chrome in android emulator?

Tags: google-chrome, automation, android-emulator, adb

When first loading an URL with ADB on a fresh Android Emulator you get a bunch of screens to set user preferences before the actual page is loaded. This is better explained visually:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com`

[image: Open with Chrome]
[image: Accept ToS]
[image: Sign in to Chrome]

I need to pass these screens without user interaction and have the requested URL loaded directly.

So the question is, how can I initialize chrome in the emulator through ADB or other means?